# How should a component access data from a store?

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

In my React app, when a user logs in, their user data is set to `UserStore.currentUser`. How should components access `UserStore.currentUser`?

It seems there are 4 options for a component to access this data. Which (if any) is correct?

**Option 1: Set it to a component's "state"**

```
  var ProfilePicture = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      return {
        currentUser: UserStore.currentUser
      }
    },
    render: function(){
      return <h1>Hi my name is {this.currentUser.name}</h1>;
    }
  });
```

**Option 2: Access the store's property directly**

```
var ProfilePicture = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <h1>Hi my name is {UserStore.currentUser.name}</h1>;
  }
});
```

**Option 3: Access the store's property through a getter method**

```
var ProfilePicture = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <h1>Hi my name is {UserStore.getCurrentUser().name}</h1>;
  }
});
```

**Option 4: Set currentUser in the root component's state. Pass as a prop to all others**

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return { currentUser: UserStore.currentUser };
  },
  render: function(){
    return <div>
      <ThingA />
      <ThingB />
      <ProfilePicture userName={this.state.currentUser.name} />
    </div>;
  }
});

var ProfilePicture = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <h1>Hi my name is {this.props.userName}</h1>;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a particularly good idea in this case. What if `name` changes? It would be better to `connect` the store to a view (component container) and pass `name` to `ProfilePicture` through a prop. That keeps your component decoupled. This also makes it easier to test.

In terms of React 0.14 I would write something like this:

```
export default ({name}) => <h1>{`Hi my name is ${name}`}</h1>
```

The function based component definition works only in simple cases.

Comment: Is that like the Option 3 I wrote here? Basically I set the state of the root application component, then pass it as a prop to child components that need it

Answer (score 0):

Your store contain the method which can give you data back like

```
getUserinfo:function()
{
  return currentUser;
}
```

now you can access any of your component you have to just call the store like

```
var UserStore=require('./UserStore);

var currentuser=UserStore.getUserinfo();
```

Comment: Isn't this a bad idea since changes to the currentUser will not cause the component to rerender?

Comment: here there is no chance of rerender because just store the current user in variable and getback wherever it's required

Comment: @DonnyP once user change your whole flux flow will be called and that changed will automatically update the current user variable so changes will apply

Answer (score 0):

```
mixins: [
    Reflux.listenTo(UserStore,'onSessionChange'),
    ],
getInitialState() {
    return {
        name: '',
        other: ''
    };
},
componentDidMount() {
    UserActions.getUserInfo();
},
onSessionChange(userInfo) {
    this.setState({
        name: userInfo.name,
        other: userInfo.other
    })
},
```

As you are using refluxjs, I think it's better to listen to the data change in component.